# determine the intervals in which the graph is increasing

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

Determine the intervals where the graph increases.

[image]

I don't know how to draw a graph here or if it is possible.

I think that the answer is B, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: Can you provide a reason why you think the answer is $B$?

Comment: @5xum i believe that its B because when you go from right to left you could see that the interval is increasing from (0,1) but i couldn't find that in the options, but there could be another reading that i don't know about which would lead to the answer B, looking from left to right it will be (1,2) from right to left it will be (-2,-1). But i suspect thats a false reading but i don't know so thats why im asking you guys here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is $(C)$ because this sine curve is *increasing* from the minima at $(-1,-1)$ to the maxima at $(1,1)$

Comment: Thank you, i misread it. i tend to split the graph in two pieces sometimes. thats why i thought that (0,1) is supposed to be the right answer when i replied to @5xum.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

The graph is *increasing* at a point $x$ if the function values of points smaller than $x$ are also smaller than $f(x)$, and function values of points larger than $x$ are larger than $f(x)$.

Looking at the graph, that means that for a given number $x$, you look at the point $P=(x,f(x))$ on the graph. The function is *increasing* if the points to the *left* of $P$ are *below* $P$ and points to the *right* of $P$ are above it.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is C) $[-1,1]$. The function is said to be increasing if $x\geq y\implies f(x)\geq f(y)$. So for the portion between $x=-1$ and $x=1$ the function value is increasing as depicted on the graph.

Answer (score 2):

We say that $f(x)$ is increasing in the interval $(a,b)$ , if for each $x_1,x_2\in (a,b)$ ,  $ x_2>x_1 \Rightarrow f(x_2)>f(x_1)$.

So the answer is $C$.

Answer (score -1):

When students struggle with these types of questions, I often encourage them to imagine that the graph represents a rollercoaster that travels from left to right. (Take a look at the image that is attached.) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdpcr.jpg) Notice that wherever the rollercoaster ride is increasing would be considered an increasing interval and wherever the ride is decreasing would be a decreasing interval. So, if you imagine that this graph represents a rollercoaster ride, it’s quite easy to see that the ride increases within the interval (-1,1). So the answer is C.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).